# Issue with React-Router rendering wrong component for dynamic route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm facing an issue with React-Router where navigating to a specific URL with a dynamic parameter is rendering the wrong component. Specifically, when navigating to `"http://localhost:3001/Create/4"`, the `Create` component is being rendered instead of the expected `Blogdetails` component associated with the ID 4.

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Components/Home';
import Blogdetails from './Components/Blogdetails';
import Create from './Components/Create';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        {/* Other components or content */}
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
          <Route path='/blogs/:id' component={Blogdetails} />
          <Route path='/Create' component={Create} />
        </Switch>
        {/* Other components or content */}
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const Blogdetails = () => {
    const { id } = useParams();
    return (
        <div className="blog-details">
            <h2>Blog Details - {id}</h2>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Blogdetails;
```

Despite rearranging the route order and verifying the `useParams` hook, the issue persists. Can someone help me identify what might be causing this unexpected behavior with React-Router?

Rearranging the route order in the `<Switch>` component to ensure the dynamic route (`"/blogs/:id"`) is before the static route (`"/Create"`). Verified the implementation of the `useParams` hook in the `Blogdetails` component to correctly extract the id parameter from the URL. Checked for any conflicting routes or conflicting paths defined in other parts of the application.

Expected Outcome:

Upon navigating to `"http://localhost:3001/Create/4"`, I expected the `Blogdetails` component to be rendered, displaying the details for the blog with ID 4. I anticipated that the route pattern `"/blogs/:id"` would match the URL and correctly render the `Blogdetails` component while extracting the id parameter.

Actual Result:

Instead of rendering the `Blogdetails` component, the application renders the `Create` component when navigating to `"http://localhost:3001/Create/4"`. Despite reordering the routes and ensuring correct implementation of the `useParams` hook, the issue persists.

```js
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";





const Navbar = () =>{

    const handleClick = (e) => {
        console.log("Hello, World", e);
    }

    const handleClickAgain = (name, e) => {
        console.log("Hello " + name, e.target);
    }

    return(
         <nav className="navbar">
            <h1>The Magnum blog</h1>
            <div className="links">
                <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                <Link to="/Create" style={{
                    color: "white",
                    backgroundColor: "#f1356d",
                    borderRadius: "8px "
                }} onClick={handleClick}>New Blog</Link>
                <button onClick={(e) => {handleClickAgain("Mario",e)}}>Another Blog</button>
            </div>
         </nav>
         
    )
}


export default Navbar;
```

```js
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";




const BlogList = ({ blogs, title}) => {
    
    
    return(
       <div className="blog-list">
        <h2>{ title }</h2>
        {blogs.map((blog) => (
                <div className="blog-preview" key={blog.id}>
                    <Link to = {`/blogs/${blog.id}`}>
                    <h2>{blog.title}</h2>
                    <p>Writtern By {blog.author}</p>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            ))}
       </div>
    )
} 

export default BlogList;
```

Comment: I'm deeply confused by what your problem.  You say you want `http://localhost:3001/Create/4` to go to the `Blogdetails` component, but your router clearly says that path a) doesn't take an ID and b) should only go to the `Create` component.  I think you're confused about how the router works.  The order doesn't matter if the routes (like the ones you presented) are sufficiently distinct.

Comment: <Route path='/blogs/:id' component={Blogdetails} />  this clearly says to take id and render blogdetails..

Comment: Yes.  But that's not the route you're using.

Comment: Where in the code you've provided are you navigating to any `"/create/4"` route? Where are the `Navbar` and `BlogList` components rendered so you can navigate in the app?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like for the path `"/create/4"` to be matched and render the `BlogDetails` then you need to render a route that can match it. Currently the `BlogDetails` component is rendered ***only on*** a `"/blogs/:id"` route, so the route `"/create"` is the next best match and the `Create` component is rendered.

Add a `"/create/:id"` route path.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        {/* Other components or content */}
        <Switch>
          <Route
            path={['/blogs/:id', '/create/:id']} // <-- specify path array
            component={BlogDetails}
          />
          <Route path='/create' component={Create} />
          <Route path='/' component={Home} />
        </Switch>
        {/* Other components or content */}
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Still problem is not solved?

Comment: @DewashishSahu Can you clarify what isn't working still? Are you saying that *even after* adding a `"/create/:id"` path for the `BlogDetails` component, and *navigating to* `"/create/4"` that the `BlogDetails` component isn't rendering?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the url `/blogs/4` directly and if there is a blog with id 4, then it should render correctly.

If you want the same effect with `Create/4`, then you would need to change your second route to `Create/:id` and corresponding links and onClick handlers.